# Using a group by and lookup table

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have 3 tables which I want to create a query from:

Entrants:
**CompetitionID

*BandID***
*BandResult*
...
...

ResultPoints:
**bandResult**
points

Band:
**BandID**
BandName

italics=foreign key, bold = primary key

This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT E.bandID, SUM(RP.points)
  FROM entrants E, resultPoints RP
 WHERE E.bandResult = RP.bandResult
 GROUP BY E.bandID
 ORDER BY SUM(RP.points) DESC;
```

I want to also include bandName but when I include this the group by stops working:

```
SELECT E.bandID, B.bandName, SUM(RP.points)
  FROM entrants E, resultPoints RP, band B
 WHERE E.bandResult = RP.bandResult
   AND B.bandID = E.bandID
 GROUP BY E.bandID
 ORDER BY SUM(RP.points) DESC;
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: So what do you want to do in the first place? Propably you just need to add B.bandName to the GROUP BY statement

Comment: yes I just needed that. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the bandName to the group by clause.

Comment: Wow how did I not see that :P Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT E.bandID, B.bandName, SUM(RP.points)
FROM entrants E, resultPoints RP, band B
WHERE E.bandResult = RP.bandResult
AND B.bandID = E.bandID
GROUP BY E.bandID, B.bandname
ORDER BY SUM(RP.points) DESC;
```